# Canvas Loads Previous Image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas with an id of cnv.

```
<canvas id='cnv'></canvas>
```

I have a javascript function that changes the image in a canvas. The images vary.

```
function changeImageInACanvas(dynamicSource){     
     var myid_signature = document.getElementById("cnv");    
     var myid_ctx_signature= myid_signature.getContext('2d');
     var myid_signature_image  = document.getElementById("img_mysignature");                                                
     myid_signature_image.src = dynamicSource;                    

     myid_ctx_signature.clearRect(0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);               

     if (myid_signature_image.complete){
         myid_ctx_signature.drawImage(myid_signature_image,0,0,  myid_signature_image.width,  myid_signature_image.height, 0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);                                                                                                
     }else{
         myid_signature_image.onload = function () {                            
             myid_ctx_signature.drawImage( myid_signature_image,0,0,  myid_signature_image.width,  myid_signature_image.height, 0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);                                                                                                   
         };                                              
     }
}
```

At the very first time, the function was executed the image loads properly in the canvas but in the second time, the previous image was displayed and the new image was not displayed.

I debug it by putting a break point in every line of the function. I discovered that the new image is loaded in the second time the function was executed, but after the function the canvas loads again the previous/first image. Where am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the declaration of your image variable from

```
var myid_signature_image  = document.getElementById("img_mysignature");
```

To

```
var myid_signature_image  = new Image();
```

Then you will be able to use the function as intended.

Quick example in this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Niddro/pyzs9m7h/)

**Updated answer:**
The onload-event is sometimes activated after the image source has ben declared. Instead declare it before.

```js
function changeImageInACanvas(dynamicSource){     
     var myid_signature = document.getElementById("cnv");    
     var myid_ctx_signature= myid_signature.getContext('2d');
     var myid_signature_image  = new Image();  
  
     myid_signature_image.onload = function () { //declare the onload-event                      
        myid_ctx_signature.clearRect(0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height); 
       myid_ctx_signature.drawImage( myid_signature_image,0,0,  myid_signature_image.width,  myid_signature_image.height, 0, 0, myid_signature.width, myid_signature.height);
                      
     }
     myid_signature_image.src = dynamicSource; //declare the source last
}


changeImageInACanvas('http://pattersonrivervet.com.au/sites/default/files/pictures/Puppy-10-icon.png');      

setTimeout(function () {
 changeImageInACanvas('https://38.media.tumblr.com/avatar_2be52b9ba912_128.png');  
},3000);
```

```html
<canvas id='cnv'></canvas>
```

Comment: Nothing's change, Any rationale of your answer?

Comment: Sorry for late answer but your html code did not include any img-tags so your variable  `myid_signature_image` would be undefined and thus not show an image. I instead defined the variable as an image in the JavaScript code. Something else that might be causing trouble is that you, in your else-statement, declare the onload event, which is declared AFTER the image source is declared.